# Gitlab pipeline doesn't start when using rule which compares changes in repository path to a variable in a configuration file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline which shall execute when there are changes in a sub structure of my repository. I compare the changes in my repository to an old commit hash. It is working fine when I am using the following rules:

```
workflow:
rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      changes:
        paths:
            - "60_2_Modultest/Firmware/SRC/**/*"
        compare_to:
            "e1a03084861006779f80fee6b882851dda0d8d51"
```

But I don't want to compare the repository to a single commit hash but to an updated commit hash which is read from another yml file. So I tried this:

```
include: 
    local: variables.yml

workflow:
    rules:
        - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
          changes:
            paths:
                - "60_2_Modultest/Firmware/SRC/**/*"
            compare_to:
                $COMPARE_COMMIT_HASH
```

The included yml file contains the variable $COMPARE_COMMIT_HASH and looks like this:

```
variables:
    COMPARE_PATH: "Modultest/Firmware/SRC/**/*"
    COMPARE_COMMIT_HASH: "e1a03084861006779f80fee6b882851dda0d8d51"
```

Still, the pipeline doesn't start. What is my mistake?

EDIT: It seems like it is generally not possible to use variables in **changes:compare_to**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. It's not yet possible to use variables in `rules:changes:compare_to:`. There is an open [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/369916) for this capability, however.

That said, your approach here could actually work with a small tweak of using `!reference` instead of a variable.

```yaml
# "variables.yml"
.compare_to:
  paths:
    - "60_2_Modultest/Firmware/SRC/**/*"
  hash: "e1a03084861006779f80fee6b882851dda0d8d51"
```

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml

include:
  - local: variables.yml

workflow:
    rules:
        - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
          changes:
            paths: !reference [.compare_to, paths]
            compare_to: !reference [.compare_to, hash]
```

Yet another option might be to use [dynamic child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines).